# How do I set a background color to the text inside anchor tag in html?

Tags: html

I want to set a background color to the innertext of a certain `<a>` tag:

```
<i class="fas fa-solid fa-download">&ensp;</i><a class="app-info" href="/filename.apk" download>You can install this app from here</a>
```

In my `css` I wrote this rule:

```
 .app-info{ background-color: "rgb(255, 214, 127)";}
```

But the background color isn't showing in my `HTML` page. Why?

Comment: The background colour should not be within quotes. You can find a reference for the syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color#syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the css rgb value won't come in the quation marks

```
.app-info{ 
       background-color: rgb(255, 214, 127);
}
```

it will now change the background color of the `anchor` tag